# Inverted index of json document

Tags: elasticsearch, inverted-index

When we talk about inverted index, we always talk about indexing unstructured text documents. But documents in ElasticSearch are in JSON format, they are "key"-"value" pairs. So I want to know how the inverted index of JSON documents looks like. In another word, when we do the search like "select * from table where name = john", what does ES do?

Answer (score 2):

An [inverted index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/inverted-index.html) basically stores a relationship between terms and the document/field they were found in. Now, those terms can come from unstructured text, but not only. A JSON document also contains text, which ES analyzes and indexes.

Basically, from a 30000 feet perspective, the way it works is that ES parses the JSON documents it receives, iterates over all fields and analyzes/tokenizes the value of all those fields. The tokens that come out of this analysis process are then indexed into the inverted index.

Long story short, it doesn't have to be unstructured text that gets indexed into an inverted index, it can also be a JSON document, etc, which also contain structured, unstructured text, but also numerical figures, dates, etc.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I know structured document like JSON document also contains text and can be indexed, but how? How does ES know which value in which field? Does ES build a small index for every field?

Comment: You got it, that's what ES does under the hood.

Comment: It is basically your term-frequency matrix stored using it's sparse representation per document. You can explore it using the termvectors API. The obvious point is that the fields have to be analyzed otherwise they will not be included in the matrix(inverted index)

Comment: @sramalingam24 they will but as a single token (i.e. a keyword)